# Understanding Lemma 4.6. of Titchmarsh's book

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory

The following is Lemma 4.6. in Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

My questions:

1- (Red-underlined) WolframAlpha gives $\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{iu}}{\sqrt{u}}$ same as in the text. For the remaining part, how $\int_{\frac12 {\delta^2} F''(c)}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{iu}}{\sqrt{u}} = O \bigg( \dfrac{1}{\delta \sqrt{\lambda_2}} \bigg)$ is derived?

2- (Blue&Green-underlined) I could not understand the other two cases. For example, how the integral in the second line of the last paragraph is evaluated?

Comment: For the first question, use integration by parts once (integrating $e^{iu}$) then the triangle inequality to bound the remaining integral

Comment: Why no answers at all? Second time I put on bounty :)